# IEnumerable<T> vs T[]

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, ienumerable

I just realize that maybe I was mistaken all the time in exposing `T[]` to my views, instead of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Usually, for this kind of code:

```
foreach (var item in items) {}
```

`item` should be `T[]` or `IEnumerable<T>`?

Than, if I need to get the count of the items, would the `Array.Count` be faster over the `IEnumerable<T>.Count()`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is generally a better choice here, for the reasons listed elsewhere. However, I want to bring up one point about `Count()`. Quintin is incorrect when he says that the type itself implements `Count()`. It's actually implemented in `Enumerable.Count()` as an extension method, which means other types don't get to override it to provide more efficient implementations.

By default, `Count()` has to iterate over the whole sequence to count the items. However, it *does* know about `ICollection<T>` and `ICollection`, and is optimised for those cases. (In .NET 3.5 IIRC it's only optimised for `ICollection<T>`.) Now the array *does* implement that, so `Enumerable.Count()` defers to `ICollection<T>.Count` and avoids iterating over the whole sequence. It's still going to be slightly slower than calling `Length` directly, because `Count()` has to discover that it implements `ICollection<T>` to start with - but at least it's still O(1).

The same kind of thing is true for performance in general: the JITted code may well be somewhat tighter when iterating over an array rather than a general sequence. You'd basically be giving the JIT more information to play with, and even the C# compiler itself treats arrays differently for iteration (using the indexer directly).

However, these performance differences are going to be inconsequential for *most* applications - I'd definitely go with the more general interface until I had good reason not to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I assume that using `IEnumerable<T>` and `Count()` is more efficient, then constructing an `T[]` just for getting the `Length` property?

Comment: @stacker: Creating a copy of a collection into an array just to get its length would certainly be less efficient than just calling `Count()`, yes.

Comment: How often do you need to get the number of elements? If you have to re-enumerate every element to get the `Count`, it could get expensive.

Comment: @Gabe only once. I'm chancing it in a variable.

Comment: @stacker: IEnumerables can be infinite in theory, therefore they have no Count. Using an array you have Length. If you find yourself needing  a count, use ICollection instead of IEnumerable.

Comment: @Johannes is using `ICollection` better than just use `count()`?

Comment: @stacker: If you use `Enumerable.Count`, that will notice if your collection implements `ICollection<T>` and use the `Count` property automatically. It's not clear exactly what you're really getting at here.

Comment: @Johannes: I mean it's not quite clear what stacker is trying to achieve, or what he's concerned about.

Comment: @Jon: Ok, just wanted to make sure. And I couldn't resist the poetic tone of these words ;-)

Comment: @Jon thanks for the answer. I just want to make sure that it's better to use IEnumerable<T> instead T[], instead the Model's, View Model's and Repositories.

Answer (score 7):

It's partially inconsequential, but standard theory would dictate "Program against an interface, not an implementation".  With the interface model you can change the actual datatype being passed without effecting the caller as long as it conforms to the same interface.

The contrast to that is that you might have a reason for exposing an array specifically and in which case would want to express that.

For your example I think `IEnumerable<T>` would be desirable.  It's also worthy to note that for testing purposes using an interface could reduce the amount of headache you would incur if you had particular classes you would have to re-create all the time, collections aren't as bad generally, but having an interface contract you can mock easily is very nice.

Added for edit:
<strike>This is more inconsequential because the underlying datatype is what will implement the `Count()` method, for an array it should access the known length, I would not worry about any perceived overhead of the method.</strike>
[See Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433284/ienumerablet-vs-t/3433412#3433412) for an explanation of the `Count()` implementation.

Comment: So, generally, I shouldn't use `T[]`, right? when *should* I use `T[]`?

Comment: @Quintin, C# arrays are not immutable.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen That's one of the reasons why I said there are caveats, I didn't want to break it down, some perceive them to be immutable although you can modify the contents of the indices.

Comment: @stacker Typically when you want to represent a perceived readonly collection or need the memory to be sequential. Of course there are caveats to this.

Comment: @Quintin if it's immutable collection (perceived readonly), that need to be iterated (I didn't get what's `the memory to be sequential` mean), didn't IEnumerable<T> better? This is exactly the case in my views.

Comment: @stacker Yes, like I said, for your purposes and probably for most general cases, `IEnumerable<T>` is better suited.

Comment: @stacker, you're correct.  If you just want to access (not modify) the elements in consecutive order, `IEnumerable` is the correct choice.  An array is appropriate when you want a fixed size collection and the ability to access and modify any element by index - [random access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access).

Comment: @Quintin Through, is there any case that I want to `T[]`? I mean if I need it to be indexed, I can use `IList<T>`.

Comment: @Matthew thanks for the link. I think you answered the question above.

Answer (score 3):

T[] (one sized, zero based) also implements `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>` with `IEnumerable<T>`.

Therefore if you want lesser coupling in your application `IEnumerable<T>` is preferable. Unless you want indexed access inside *foreach*.

Answer (score 3):

Since Array class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces, I would use IEnumerable, unless you need to use these interfaces.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your gut feeling is correct, if all the view cares about, or should care about, is having an enumerable, that's all it should demand in its interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

What is it logically (conceptually) from the outside?

If it's an array, then return the array. If the only point is to enumerate, then return IEnumerable. Otherwise IList or ICollection may be the way to go.

If you want to offer lots of functionality but not allow it to be modified, then perhaps use a List internally and return the ReadonlyList returned from it's .AsReadOnly() method.

Answer (score 0):

Given that changing the code from an array to IEnumerable at a later date is easy, but changing it the other way is not, I would go with a IEnumerable until you know you need the small spead benfit of return an array.